# Format and parser for Celery-Flower's Database

Tags: python, celery, flower

Will just ask if Celery-Flower's database (i.e when you use --persisten=True --db=flower) has a specific format? If yes, what is it? And are there any parsers for it, aside from flower itself?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is using [Shelve](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html), which is essentially a dictionary of pickled objects. You can use the same technique to read it. Check out [the code](https://github.com/mher/flower/blob/master/flower/events.py#L97), should give you a good starting point. Keep in mind that this is not a "published feature", hence, the project author might choose to change it at any given point. I'd suggest trying to use [the API](http://flower.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html) for your needs.

Comment: Do you know whether or not it is possible to modify the flower.db file? I want to be able to remove some of the tasks that gets persisted in there.